Angular reactive forms dynamically added inputs not accepting input
I have a section where the user selects a type of element and a set of inputs are displayed based on that selection. This works as expected, with no error but the user can't type inside any elements added via the ngFor loop. I have a "hard coded" input that's added on the selection, called "test", but outside the loop and it accepts input just fine
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>test</mat-label>
          <input matInput />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field *ngFor="let currentControl of currentControls(currentNode.controls)">
          <mat-label>{{currentControl.label}}</mat-label>
          <input matInput [formControlName]="currentControl.control" />
        </mat-form-field>

I get the correct inputs, labels, and the inspector shows the correct formControlName is being used. For clarity currentNode is the current target from a formArray. I pass in currentNode.controls and currentControls() passes back an array with the control name and label.
edit - more complete view of template code:
<ng-container formArrayName="nodes">
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let currentNode of nodes.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          {{getNodeTitle(i)}}
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      
      <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>test</mat-label>
          <input matInput />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field *ngFor="let currentControl of currentControls(currentNode.controls)">
          <mat-label>{{currentControl.label}}</mat-label>
          <input matInput [formControlName]="currentControl.control" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </ng-template>

    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</ng-container>


Does currentControlls array items preserve reference on each render? Have you tried adding trackBy expression?

@kvetis I'm not using trackBy, I don't think I've used that expression before (surprisingly). I updated the question with more details.

@kvetis adding a simple trackby against the index seems to have resolved it, thanks!
